# Is my derivation of the tetrahedral bond angle correct?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification, polyhedra, platonic-solids

Let $T$ be a regular tetrahedron with edge length $x$.

Let $A$ be one of the faces of $T$.

Let $P$ be the plane containing $A$.

Let $L$ be the line segment from the center of $A$ to one of the vertices of $A$.

Let $H$ be the shortest line segment from $P$ to the vertex of $T$ that is not in the plane $P$.

Let $E$ be the edge of $T$ that forms a right-angled triangle together with $L$ and $H$.

Since $A$ is by definition an equilateral triangle, then the length of $L$ is $\frac{x}{√3}$.

Therefore, the angle between $H$ and $E$ is $\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{√3})$.

Let $\alpha = \sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{√3})$.

Since the tetrahedral bond angle is the remaining angle of an isosceles triangle whose other two angles are each equal to $\alpha$, then the tetrahedral bond angle is $$π-2\alpha=2(π/2-\alpha)=2(π/2-\arcsin(\frac{1}{√3}))=2\cos^{-1}(\frac{1}{√3}).$$

Comment: The easiest way to do this kind of calculation is to note that in the cube [-1, 1]^3, alternate vertices form the vertices of a regular tetrahedron and the origin is its center. Then use the fact that the dot product of two unit vectors is equal to the cosine of their angle.

Comment: @DanAsimov So, to summarize your method: Suppose u = <-1,1,1> and v = <1,-1,1>. These point to 2 alternate vertices of the cube [-1,1]^3. The cosine of the angle between them is  -1/3, which is the cosine of the tetrahedral bond angle.

Comment: It's worthwhile to evaluate the inverse cosine to check whether the approximate number of degrees looks geometrically correct.

Comment: @DanAsimov 2arccos(1/√3) = arccos(-1/3) which is approximately 109.5 degrees

Comment: You know three of the vertices are the vertices of an equilateral triangle. If you assume one vertex is at the origin (0,0,0), one is at (1,0,0), the other at $(1/2, \sqrt{3}/2,0)$, you can find the fourth point $(x,y,z)$, by assuming it is $1$ unit from all the other points. After you get the 4th point, add up all the coordiantes and divide by 4 to get the center of mass, C. Now you can find two vectors pointing from C to any of the other points and take the dot product. The arccos of that gives you the angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks OK to me. Well done!

Comment: Thanks for looking it over. One advantage I see of my method is that it does not use coordinates. Aside from that, I've greatly enjoyed seeing the other available methods mentioned so far